# Installing windows service and typical path to store settings(data)

Tags: c#, windows

I am beginner with Windows services and would like to ask you couple of questions. I did some research but still some questions remain, and I would like to clarify.

First of all, I developed standard windows service using C#.
Now, I need to install it on different machine.

*Question1* : What are the ways I can Install it on different machine?

*Question2* : Is installation same depending whether that other computer
has or has not Visual Studio installed?

Finally, I heard one might need to use some kind of installer (is this the only way?). Say user specifies folder Program Files where to install the service. Does this mean the service executable e.g., `myservice.exe` will be copied in program files folder? I am asking this because I want
to use `BaseDirectory` from the service to read some settings file(this will return probably path like `C:\Program Files\MyService\`), and I read somewhere on Windows 7 you might not even be allowed to write to Program files.
If that is so, which folder is typically used to store settings, logs for Windows service?

Answer (score 0):

*Answer 1*: If you have an implemented C# .NET Windows service, then you can install it using `sc create` and `net start`:

```
set p=%~dp0  
sc create %1YourServiceName binpath= %p%YourServiceName.exe start=auto  
net start %1YourServiceName
```

The service will be installed on a local machine and immediatelly run.

*Answer 2*: No. You don't need Visual Studio to be installed on the target machine to start this service. However, you need .NET FrameWork of corresponding version to be installed.

*Answer 3*: I don't know which installer you are using. If a users specifies the Program Files folder as install destination then, most probably, executable will be copied there.

If you use the approach which I have described in the p.1 then the executable path of exe will be the current. Create folder "C:\YourServiceName", copy your win service bins there and run this batch script there. Your executable path will be "C:\YourServiceName" and let it always be there.

By the way, if you need, you can get the executing path of your windows service from code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Also, it is stored in your registry:

```
SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/services/YourServiceName/ImagePath
```

Comment: I asked this question about how to install service on a *different* machine than mine?